# Not a question, but a 'post'

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I want to give an explanation about something so other people will stop asking for it on a Stack Exchange site. Now how can I do that? I am not asking a question so I will need to post it in another way. Maybe there should be an option to not ask a question but make a 'post' or so, to explain some stuff so other users can still see it - but they won't have to create a question for it.

You may not understand this as it's a bit vague, I will edit my question when I have the time...

Thanks for considering.

Comment: Can you make it into a question-answer pair? Surely you can...

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you mean that I could just open a question and give the answer too in the OP?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to give an explanation

Explaining what? Surely an issue, or a question to be resolved, right?

So...

Make it a two part post - a question and an answer to it.

Ensure both parts follow our quality guidelines and you are good to go.

You can even post them at the same time, using the "Answer your own question" checkbox on the ask a question page.

Comment: I mean the answer to an issue that many users have => they don't have to ask the question because it's already suggested when typing the title and/or content of the question. Thanks for your reply - I can do something with this!

Comment: You mean a canonical answer?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. What do you mean with 'canonical'?

Comment: It means an answer that is the definite answer to a certain question. Something so good that we can point askers of similar questions to it.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean :)